# URLRequest multiple SWF links not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I'm trying to load 3 different tickers in 3 different containers.
When I delete this line:

```
 loader2.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=bl&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));
 loader3.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=bl&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));
```

and load them separately they works fine:

[image]

but when i load them together, just as the written in [this document](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html) in adobe, all three tickers showing the same number:

[image]

```
package  {    
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;


public class importExternalSWF extends MovieClip {
    private var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    private var loader2:Loader = new Loader();
    private var loader3:Loader = new Loader();

    public function importExternalSWF() {
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=mrj-4&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));
        loader2.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=bl&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));
        loader3.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=grel&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));

        ticker1.addChild(loader);
        ticker1.width=50;
        ticker1.height=20;

        ticker2.addChild(loader2);
        ticker2.width=50;
        ticker2.height=20;

        ticker3.addChild(loader3);
        ticker3.width=50;
        ticker3.height=20;      
        }
    }
}
```

I cant find solution anywhere

Thanks

edit
I rewrite my code to this, and its still the same result

```
public class importExternalSWF extends MovieClip {

    public function importExternalSWF() {

        var url = "http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf";
        var urlParams:Array = ["grel", "bl", "game=mrj-4"];
        var tickers:Array = [ticker1, ticker2, ticker3];
        var tickerHeight:Number = 50;
        var tickerWidth:Number = 50;

        loadUrls();

        function loadUrls():void {

            for(var i:uint = 0; i<urlParams.length; i++)
            {
                var urlLoader = new Loader();
                var flashvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
                flashvars["casino"] = "cityclub";
                flashvars["info"] = "1";
                flashvars["game"] = urlParams[i];
                flashvars["currency"] = "eur";
                flashvars["font_face"] = "arial";
                flashvars["bold"] = "true";
                flashvars["font_size"] = "10";
                flashvars["bg_color"] = "0x000000";
                flashvars["font_color"] = "ffffff";

                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
                request.data = flashvars;
                urlLoader.load(request);

                tickers[i].width=tickerWidth;
                tickers[i].height=tickerHeight;
                tickers[i].addChild(urlLoader);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the 'para' parameter have an affect on the SWF?  I didn't think you could pass parameters directly to a SWF.  Why are you passing the para argument twice?

Comment: that SWF must have parameters to work properly. as you see in the images, its working, but only separately. when its together, the last link override the previous URL load.

Comment: How does the rest of the code looks like ? how do you handle the load complete ?

Comment: except click listeners that's all i got. 
after watching a lot of tutorials and didn't noticed any instruction for completion handlers, if I one of those please advice me :)

Comment: Did you try to use Charles and see if 3 requests are actually sent? Did you compare `loaderInfo`?

Comment: added `loaderInfo` for each loader and each one is loading different URL as it should be.

Comment: I may have missed something. Why does para get passed twice?

Comment: its just a fake link, the actual link is the same, with different parameters each link

Comment: I used 'Fiddler' to see what requests flash sending to the server, and found out the he sends 3 same links although i wrote him to send 3 different links...

Comment: @Mitz Please, can you post a code of ticker.swf? i'm trying to replicate your problem.

Comment: @GastonF. I've updated the edit with the right link and information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no solution to this issue due to lack of compatibility from third part company that provides the tickers.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the external SWF file sets some variables on the root level. Therefore each load will override the previous values and you'll end up with the same score in all "tickers".

Most likely this interference can be resolved by loading each SWF into its own `ApplicationDomain`. By default, SWFs are being loaded into the same [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) and share their code.

So instead of doing this:

```
urlLoader.load(request);
```

You should do soemthing like this:

```
// create a new LoaderContext with a spearate ApplicationDomain
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain());

// load the request and use the context with the separate ApplicationDomain
urlLoader.load(request, context);
```

Comment: That's what I though, I will try it tomorrow morning and I'll update. thanks a lot.

Comment: its not working for some reason, the result is the same, but its must be a direction

Answer (score 3):

I have bad news, i tried everything, but I can't load correctly the swf files. So, I have started to investigate this, and i found that, first, your SWF has AVM1Movie format (new_jackpot.swf), so, I conclude that this SWF was created with version 1 or 2 of ActionScript. If you see the reference of  **AVM1Movie** Class (here the [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html)), says the following:

**There are several restrictions on an AVM1 SWF file loaded by an AVM2 SWF file:**

- **The AVM1 SWF file that is loaded by an AVM2 SWF file cannot load another SWF file into this. That is, it cannot load another SWF file over itself. However, child Sprite objects, MovieClip objects, or other AVM1 SWF files loaded by this SWF file can load into this.**

Then, i tried too, with a library that implements Threads in Flex, and found this (here this link [async-threading](http://code.google.com/p/async-threading/)):

- **The Actionscript Virtual Machine (AVM) in the Flash Player is severely limited by only having one thread...**

I have created several projects using Loaders, SWFLoaders, ByteArrays, etc, all this in actionscript 3 in Flex SDK 3.2. 
Maybe if you create this project in a previous version could work, or try to use same library that implements threads.

Anyway if I find something more, will edit this answer with another solution that's right.

Comment: Good info. It seems it would be simpler for the asker to implement such a ticker/counter himself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try the suggestions.

@bummzack I thought about doing that, but the "ticker" is provided by third-party company, we got no access to their data.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a 1 after «laoder» at these places:

```
private var loader:Loader = new Loader();
```

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://tickers.playtech.com/jackpots/new_jackpot.swf?casino=cityclub&info=1&game=mrj-4&font_face=Arial&bold=true&font_color=FFFFFF&bg_color=240000&font_size=24&currency=eur"));
```

Comment: you can see my edit I wrote few days ago, I rewrote my code then